# How to fix "updatedb: can not find group ` mlocate'" on entware?

Tags: linux, group, updatedb

I have installed the `mlocate` package on Asus RT-N56U running Padavan with Entware-ng, which is based on OpenWrt. This embedded Linux distribution has SSH enabled.

My `locate` results are out of date. When I use the `updatedb` command this error appears:

> ```
> updatedb: can not find group mlocate
> ```

How can I fix this, preferably with one liner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `addgroup` package is necessary and is included in busybox of padavan firmware.

Do the following steps as root:

```
grep -s mlocate /etc/group || addgroup mlocate
chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate
chmod g=rx,o= /opt/var/mlocate
chgrp mlocate /opt/bin/locate
chmod g+s,go-w /opt/bin/locate
touch /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db
chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

This is the one-liner (a single copy and paste command) to fix the "updatedb: can not find group mlocate" message:

```
# grep -s mlocate /etc/group || addgroup mlocate;chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate;chmod g=rx,o= /opt/var/mlocate;chgrp mlocate /opt/bin/locate;chmod g+s,go-w /opt/bin/locate;touch /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db;chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue with Plesk on Ubuntu 18.04. Running `addgroup mlocate` solved it, apparently no other steps were needed.

Answer (score 0):

for those that don't have the `addgroup` package.

use this command instead
`synogroup -add mlocate`

```
grep -s mlocate /etc/group || synogroup -add mlocate
chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate
chmod g=rx,o= /opt/var/mlocate
chgrp mlocate /opt/bin/locate
chmod g+s,go-w /opt/bin/locate
touch /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db
chgrp mlocate /opt/var/mlocate/mlocate.db
```